# Calculate execution time of a program based on CPI, instructions, etc

Tags: performance, assembly, mips, cpu

I'm trying to calculate the execution time of an application. Assuming the only stall penalty occurs on memory access instructions (100 cycles being the penalty).
How am I supposed to find out execution time in seconds with this info?

```
CPI (CPUCycles?) = 1.0
ClockRate = 1GHZ
TotalInstructions = 59880
MemoryAccessInstructions = 8467
CacheMissRate = 62% (0.62) (5290/8467)
CacheHits = 3117
CacheMisses = 5290
CacheMissPenalty = 100 (cycles)
```

Assuming no other penalties.

Comment: _"How am I supposed to find out execution time in seconds with this info?"_ By adding up all the costs. Did you find something in the information unclear? If so, what?

Comment: I'm not sure what the formula is to add up the costs.

Comment: You know the Cycles Per Instruction, the number of instructions, the number of memory accesses that results in cache misses, and the cost of a cache miss. It's just addition and multiplication after that.

Comment: ... *with* the realization what the CPU actually does is pretty hard to predict manually (which accesses will hit the cache?), so that your calculation is extremely likely to be suspect.  If you understand that your calculation has these kinds of assumptions/errors in it, then as @Michael said, it is a matter of adding up the costs of the individual instructions.  What he didn't say is you will likely also need to account for the costs of loops (how many times does each loop run, something you also don't know exactly).   In general, teh easiest way to get a good estimate is *measure* it.

Comment: @IraBaxter: I interpreted this as a purely theoretical excercise where `TotalInstructions` reperesents the total number of instructions executed within the time that the OP needs to calculate.

Comment: @Michael: I'm in agreement; doing this is useful in *theory*, and in practice as a raw estimate understanding its shortcomings. OP needs to understand that.

Answer (score 0):

totalCycles = TotalInstructions + CacheMisses * CacheMissPenalty ?

I assume that cache hits cost same as other opcodes, so those are included in TotalInstructions.

That's then 588880 cycles, 1GHz is 1000000000 cycles per second.
So that code will take 0.58888ms to execute (5.8888e-7 second).

This value is of course purely theoretical estimate, as modern CPU doesn't work like that (1 instruction = 1 cycle). If you are interested in real world values, just profile it.